# Do I need to checksum the file at browser side then checksum and compare them at server side?

Tags: javascript, web, checksum, consistent-hashing

In my website , some important files will be uploaded, do I need to calculate the file's checksum with `JavaScript` at the browser side, then calculate again with `golang` and compare them at the server side to make sure the files got by server are consistent?

Comment: Is it even possible to checksum a file in clientside javascript?

Comment: @Marie Isn't it possible?

Comment: Do you have any more info, like how many bits they will be and what hardware you are running to calculate the checksums? Not sure but it might help folks to answer the question for you?

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter, thank you, I added program language info to the content.

Comment: Awesome. This sort of checksum query is a little above my level at the moment but hopefully someone will come along soon and the extra info will help to get your question answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently i am developing javascript for uploading files. It is definitivly possible.
You can put a webworker in your javascript and let it do the calculations.

Webworker Info:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

I use crypto-js to calculate the checksums.

Checksums:
https://code.google.com/archive/p/crypto-js/

Some problems can occur when the files you want to upload are large. In my case for example, files bigger then 40MB causes browser crashes or OutOfMemory-Exceptions.
But if you try to upload small files, this maybe will work for you.

To awnser your question. It is not neccesarry to compare checksums. But it is a way to be sure about the files consistency. (A matter of opinion)

I used this method for over a year now and never had a checksum inconsistency after an upload.

Excuse me for my english. It's not my native language. ^^